# Flex Drain - personal opinion from an experienced user

Tags: pipe, drainage, landscaping

I am now working on extending my downspout under the sidewalk. Not something too complicated, just to distance the water a few extra feet away from the house.  While researching about different pipe options  (PVC or Corrugated) I found a product by [Flex Drain](http://www.flex-drain.com/).

This looks like a very simple product to use for this type of small project (DIY) that will suit my needs. Unfortunately I couldn’t find a favorable review when comparing this type of pipe vs Corrugated and PVC regarding strength and necessary slope (debris).

I would like to get someone’s personal opinion from an experienced user.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I have no experience of that product, but since it seems to be even thinner corrugated, and I do have experience of corrugated, I would suggest smooth, rigid pipe with fittings, 10 times out of 10, as being a far better bet for the long term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flex Pipe is very light duty compared to other drainage pipe I have used I would not recommend it for shallow underground use because it crushes quite easily when stretched to full length. The one thing I do like about it is that if you use it on the surface to extend gutters for a couple of months it is easy to collapse and store during the summer months. It is also easier to bend around shrubs than standard corrugated pipe. I don't know how long it will last collapsing and stretching out each year because I only purchased it just under 2 years ago.